# GCP kubernetes web app - User authentication using Azure AD

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a web app deployed in GKE, and we need to authenticate via Azure AD. the access is limited to the web app, not to other GCP components.
because we have a limited nr of users, we manually created those users in the app and those users also exist in Azure AD.
just wanted to get a view from the expert on what is the best way to implement the authentication?

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your goal to authenticate users of your webapp (which is hosted on GKE) to Azure AD?

Comment: hi Gari, yes absolutely that's my goal.

Comment: What language is your app written in?

Comment: But given the authentication is at the application level, I'd recommend using OIDC with Azure AD ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oidc ).

Comment: its java. yes i came across this document, it's great! thanks for the input. it makes all sense. i considered using SAML, but definitely in this case it makes sense to use OIDC or OAuth2. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is that only web app should get access then you need not to worry much as when you configure auth using Azure AD then Azure Ad is smart to issue token to google app engine and you cant use the same token with any other resource. To get more clarity please open https://jwt.ms and paste the token there to understand for whom the toke is issue to and what is the expiration time of token.

Also please refer GCP documentation https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on#configuring_azure_ad_provisioning

Comment: thanks Rohit for the feedback! i have decided to go for oauth authentication and registered the app in azure ad.